# Is a check paid to me still cashable despite mistakenly writing a bank's name on the back and checking the box for 'mobile/remote deposit'?

Tags: check, lawsuit-settlement

I received a check for settlement money. Due to how long it took to receive the check, I need to be able to cash the one I have now, if possible.

I naively wrote the name of my bank for PayPal, thinking that was needed to approve the digital scan.

Can I cash it in person in its current state (with an explanation to the cashier), or would it be advisable to use a pen-eraser?

Answer (score 5):

> or would it be advisable to use a pen-eraser?

**Never** use a pen eraser on a check.  That's a big fat red flag for fraud.

Comment: Where the pen eraser would, in theory, be applied would be on the 'remote deposit' portion. If it's my money, it appears that common sense would indicate it couldn't be fraud, as the remote deposit would be removing my own money (but now I would be undoing that). Is this correct? Also, isn't there some other way to validate the check (via phone call, for instance)?

Comment: @Phillip "If it's my money"... you misunderstand what fraud is.

Comment: i.e. 'if it's endorsed to me' - just a colloquialism I didn't think required explanation (but it appears, as such too common [in society today], you feel contradicted, so you try to find a cheap way to avert the question and invalidate my own. Grow up).

Comment: Also, you could provide a better alternative: Off the top of my head: write a line through the portion and date it.

Comment: @Phillip **any alteration** is any indication of fraud, and will gum up the works.

Comment: innocent until proven guilty - In all likelihood, it is a corrected mistake - and I'm sure there is another way to validate the check. If someone is attempting fraud, they are actually much LESS likely to make a mistake. Think about it.

Comment: @Phillip my answer was only about the pen eraser.  People have been using strike outs since the first use of checks, but I don't know how phone apps react to them.

Comment: the point is, this all skirted the additional question, but moving on, Thank you anyway. I already assume they can't take fraud out of the equation

Comment: @Phillip you ask for advice, and then argue.  Take it or leave it, but don't argue.

Comment: The next stop will be in person at check cashing store (I don't have a bank). Glad I didn't use the pen eraser yet, but hopefully I don't nullify my chances by showing it with the mistake first.

Comment: @Phillip they'll probably say to strike through it.

Comment: The point isn't an argument besides getting the requisite salient info; "arguments" are only necessary when a point addressed is ignored (which is your prerogative).

Comment: That helps RonJohn. Thanks again. You can have any final word.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to visit your bank in person, it may be best to ask the bank teller for their advice. Likely they will allow you to endorse and deposit the check, but it doesn't hurt to ask first.

Comment: Oddball occurrences are why I like to bank with a Bank that has a local branch.